# Assistance finishing VBA code for User Form in Excel

Tags: excel, forms, vba

I am new to the whole User Forms and VBA thing, but been trying to figure out how to do one for the last day or so, many YouTube videos and Google Searches later, I am still not finding the answers. I have never written any code before, so I know I am in over my head.

I am using Excel 2013 on a Windows 8 laptop.

I am trying to build a basic calculator that a user inputs values into, selects calculate and it produces the results for someone to hand write into a logbook. I have the formulas and calculations in an Excel spreadsheet, but I want something a little more professional looking than that.

All data on the left (Dry Weight, Fuel In, Fuel Out, Engine Start Time, Launch Time & Land Time) is input by the user.
All data on right (Launch Weight, Landing Weight, Engine Run Time, Flight Time, Fuel Consumed, Fuel Burn) needs to be calculated from the values input on the left.

I was able to find out how to do the calculate, reset and quit functions for those buttons, and have even figured out how to calculate the Launch Weight, Landing Weight and Fuel Consumed. I am having difficulty trying to find the code to calculate the times.

So far, here is the code I have -

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click()
LaunchWeightCalculation = Val(DryWeightEntry.Value) + Val(FuelInEntry)
LandingWeightCalculation = Val(DryWeightEntry.Value) + Val(FuelOutEntry)
FuelConsumedCalculation = Val(FuelInEntry.Value) - Val(FuelOutEntry)

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub QuitButton_Click()
Calculator.Hide
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ResetButton_Click()
Unload Calculator
Calculator.Show
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Here are all my Entry Box Names -
DryWeightEntry
FuelInEntry
FuelOutEntry
EngineStartTimeEntry
LaunchTimeEntry
LandTimeEntry
LaunchWeightCalculation
LandingWeightCalculation
EngineRunTimeCalculation
FlightTimeCalculation
FuelConsumedCalculation
FuelBurnCalculation

I wish to have the Engine Start Time, Launch Time and Land Time to auto fill to HH:MM format when enterer 1234 format.

Here are the codes I am having issues with in VBA -
EngineRunTimeCalculation = LaunchTimeEntry minus EngineStartTimeEntry
FlightTimeCalculation = LandTimeEntry minus LaunchTimeEntry

I also need it to function so that if the Hot Fuel / Adjusted Fuel in at Launch box is checked it calculates it different than if it is not.

If Checked - FuelBurnCalculation = FuelConsumedCalculation divided by FlightTimeCalculation
If Not Checked - FuelBurnCalculation = FuelConsumedCalculation divided by EngineRunTimeCalculation

I learned how to make this a module so that the user opens the excel spreadsheet and then clicks on a button and this User Form pops up. Is there a way to make it automatically pop up when they open the file? I do not need to record or keep any of the date input, we manually log the results in our personal log books, this is just a shortcut to getting the answers rather than manual calculating it all (and avoid user errors).

If anyone can help me, I will return the favor in the form of a souvenir from our Flight Crew based in Afghanistan.

Thanks for your time and let me know if you need anything else. Like I said, i think I am in over my head and tired of spending hours looking for the answers.

DTB

Comment: It is difficult to read/understand your some of your questions (format & wording). It may be easier to read if you separate them more clearly.
Your first question to do with "HH:MM" seems to lack information. Your last question is the most clear - the answer to it is the "On_Open()" sub

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to do with this question, so I will post the answers and questions I have for as many as possible, and will try to circle back and edit the answer. I believe that this question may require a rewrite.

> 1: I wish to have the Engine Start Time, Launch Time and Land Time to
>   auto fill to HH:MM format when enterer 1234 format.

Use a date time picker control from the below link, then Insert>More Controls> Microsoft Date and Time Picker 6.0. It reads easily and more controllable than a textbox. You will have to adjust the Format property of the control to the output that you like.

Use this link for installation instruction

social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0d3642b9-4e97-4fb5-9f75-2d1b7477a278/missing-microsoft-date-and-time-picker

http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/MSCOMCT2.cab

> 2:  EngineRunTimeCalculation = LaunchTimeEntry minus
>   EngineStartTimeEntry; FlightTimeCalculation = LandTimeEntry minus LaunchTimeEntry

You mention an issue, is this related to the previous formatting issue?

> 3: I also need it to function so that if the Hot Fuel / Adjusted Fuel
>   in at Launch box is checked it calculates it different than if it is not.

You should use an If Statement with an OptionButton in your command button click module to accomplish this

```
If OptionButton1 = False then

FuelBurnCalculation = FuelConsumedCalculation / FlightTimeCalculation

Else 'The optionbutton1 is on

FuelBurnCalculation = FuelConsumedCalculation / EngineRunTimeCalculation

End If
```

> I learned how to make this a module so that the user opens the excel
>   spreadsheet and then clicks on a button and this User Form pops up. Is
>   there a way to make it automatically pop up when they open the file?

You are interested in a worksheet event module. I would encourage to visit

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/
and mrexcel dot com

Both have excellent resources.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 
 YourUserFormNameHere
End Sub
```

Let me know if this is what you needed.